# HikariCP - Idle Timout property is not overriding

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Inspite of overriding the HikariCP idleTimeout property "hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", connection is not releasing after threshold. I am using sql command **SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST** to analyze the connections.

```
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url"    value="${DATABASE_URL}"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="${DATABASE_USERNAME}"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="1800000"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="60000"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout" value="180000" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="10"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5"/>
```

Comment: I am testing using JMeter. I executed 50 queries. Max connections created = 10 which is fine. But after execution none of the connections timeout as per idleTimout value they took maxLifeTime to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `-` at the end of `hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime` causing you problems?

```
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="1800000"/> -
```

Comment: is not the issue. I am testing using JMeter. I executed 50 queries. Max connections created = 10 which is fine. But after execution none of the connections timeout as per idleTimout value they took maxLifeTime to timeout